# Cant change state of data vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I create weather app and made some component which has fields in data section, then in methods section I changed value of fields and try to get it in other method but I get old value(value was not changed)

```html
<template>
    <div id = "container">
    </div>
  </template>
  
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
    },
    data () {
      return {
        city: '',
        region: '',
        country: '',
        //      Geographical coordinates (latitude, longitude)
        lat: 0,
        lon: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async getGeolocationInformation () {
        const API_KEY = 'REPLACE_WITH_VALID_API_KEY'
        const API_URL = 'https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + API_KEY
        const apiResponse = await fetch(API_URL)
        const data = await apiResponse.json()
        const { city, country, region } = data
        this.$data.city = city
        this.region = region
        this.country = country
        this.lon = 100
      },
      getCoordinatesCityByName () {
       alert(this.lon)
      },
      setCity (city){
        this.city = city
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.getGeolocationInformation()
      this.getCoordinatesCityByName() 
    },
}
</script>
```

I tried to read some articles,but the same code worked there,but not for me

Comment: You might want to invalidate this API key and request a new one, also look into .env or alternatives for storing and keeping private credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are calling the getCoordinatesCityByName() method immediately after calling the getGeolocationInformation() method in the created() lifecycle hook. However, the getGeolocationInformation() method is asynchronous, meaning it takes some time to fetch the data from the API and update the values.

When you call getCoordinatesCityByName(), it is executed before the asynchronous operation of getGeolocationInformation() completes, so you are trying to access the lon property before it has been updated with the new value.

To ensure that you access the updated value, you need to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete before calling getCoordinatesCityByName(). One way to achieve this is by using async/await syntax within the created() hook.

Keep in mind not to store API keys in your code ;-)

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      city: '',
      region: '',
      country: '',
      lat: 0,
      lon: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getGeolocationInformation() {
      const API_KEY = 'c3ee06c52efd44b08f2eeade4bc574d9'
      const API_URL = 'https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + API_KEY
      const apiResponse = await fetch(API_URL)
      const data = await apiResponse.json()
      const { city, country, region } = data
      this.city = city
      this.region = region
      this.country = country
      this.lon = 100
    },
    getCoordinatesCityByName() {
      alert(this.lon)
    },
    setCity(city) {
      this.city = city
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getGeolocationInformation()
    this.getCoordinatesCityByName()
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getGeolocationInformation` function is `asynchronous`, and the `getCoordinatesCityByName` function will execute before the API return the response and set the values, so you need to `await` it to only execute the `getCoordinatesCityByName` function after `getGeolocationInformation`.

```
    async created () {
      await this.getGeolocationInformation()
      this.getCoordinatesCityByName() 
    },
```